# Addition of values

Tags: sed, awk, solaris, ksh, line-editor

`foo.txt`:

```
Lillypaul_sg
204803
204803
204803
Ammy_sg
3
ramaswamy_sg
3
33
tommy_sg
3
3
137374
100
```

Desired `Out.txt` :

```
Lillypaul_sg
614409
Ammy_sg
3
ramaswamy_sg
36
tommy_sg
137480
```

The output is a sum of values in the input file. Headers may contain alpha numeric values but always ends with "_sg".

Comment: How can we know what is a header and what a value? Will all headers be only letters and `_` and all values be numerical? Will all headers contain a `_`? Can we use that to identify them? Also, please show us i) what you've done so far so we don't give you solutions you've already tried and ii) your _actual_ desired output, including the leading 0s you mention so we know exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Do you no longer want the numbers to be 0-padded?

Comment: I changed the question description. I just need the addition of values between each header. No need to append with leading 0's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '$0 == $0+0{
                summ += $0
                next}
               {
                if(summ)
                    format="%06d\n%s\n"
                else
                    format="%s%s\n"
                printf format, summ, $0
                summ=""}
     END       {
                if(summ)
                    printf "%06d\n", summ}' foo.txt
```

Comment: Cant i do this in a One line command with out using a script? i prefer to use multiple awks with pipe '|'. Can you do it like that?

Comment: @ayrton_senna This _is_ a one liner. Just paste it directly into your terminal. Costas has just expanded it for readability but it's the same as `awk '$0==$0+0{summ += $0;next}{if(summ){format="%06d\n%s\n"}else{format="%s%s\n"} printf format, summ, $0; summ=""} END{if(summ) print summ}'  file`

Comment: @ayrton_senna It is online command. The newline is the same as `;`. Or you can store all between `'` as separate file and call `awk -f separate.file foo.txt`

Comment: @terdon Perfect!!. Thank you. Whenever i see an expanded version of one liner commands, i try to paste them in note pad and adjust it as one line. But due to my lack of knowledge on syntax. i always makes mistakes in rearranging them into 1 line. Your comment helped me. I will practise more.

Comment: @ayrton_senna You can put expanded command directly into shell

Comment: @Costas Thanks, but if want to use it in a script i dont want the script to be too lengthy, thats why i wanted to convert them into one-liners. Any tips on how to convert your expanded version to one liners without syntax errors in future?

Comment: @ayrton_senna the variants are described above: substitute newline by `;` or put script into separate file.

Answer (score 1):

In Perl:

```
$ perl -lne 'if(/_sg/){print "$n\n$s" if defined($n); $n=$_; $s=0;}
             else{$s+=$_}END{print "$n\n$s"}' file 
Lillypaul_sg
614409
Ammy_sg
3
ramaswamy_sg
36
tommy_sg
137480
```

If you want the numbers to be 0-padded if they're less than 6 digits (as in your original question):

```
$ perl -lne 'if(/_sg/){printf "%s\n%0.6d\n",$n,$s if defined($n); $n=$_; $s=0;}
             else{$s+=$_}END{printf "%s\n%0.6d\n",$n,$s}' file
```

Comment: i can not use perl

Comment: @terdon - the q is tagged `solaris` - probably no `perl`.

Comment: @mikeserv yeah, saw that after posting. Costas already gave a fine awk solution so I'll just leave this here in case the next person to stumble across it has a proper OS ;)

Comment: @terdon - tell me about it. considering how much it costs, you'd figure the Sun folks would provide code which has seen the light of a text editor since the 80s. And that is a good answer - glad to see a post from him, too.